# Python RegEx for this HTML String

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I've got a string which is like that:

```
<span class=\"market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee\">\r
\t\t\t\t\t&#36;92.53 USD\t\t\t\t<\/span>
```

I need to find this string via RegEx. My try:

```
(^<span class=\\"market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee\\">\\r\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t&)
```

But my problem is, the count of "\t" and "\r" may vary.. And of course this is not the Regular Expression for the whole string.. Only for a part of it.

So, what's the correct and full RegEx for this string?

Comment: Don't do that. Don't parse html with regex. Try some html parsers like beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question about the Regex:

```
"market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee\\">[\\r]*[\\t]*&
```

This will catch the string you need. Even if you add more \t's or \r's.
If you need to edit this Regex I advice you to visit [this](https://www.regex101.com/r/kK7dI8/1) website and test-modify it. It will also help you to understand how regular expression works and build your own complete RegEx.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I've been searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an HTML string, I would suggest using *an HTML Parser* like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Here is an example approach finding the element by class attribute value using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = "my HTML data" 

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
result = soup.select("span.market_listing_price.market_listing_price_with_fee")
```

See also:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thank you! I'll use this function in my next project!